# FOSUserBundle missing parameter token for password reset issue

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a Symfony 3 CRM, but there seems to be an issue with the password resetting (for which I am using FOS User Bundle). A user can enter their email, they get the email with a link, but when they reach the page to change their password, the following error is logged:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some
>   mandatory parameters are missing ("token") to generate a URL for route
>   "fos_user_resetting_reset".") in FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig at
>   line 54.

So, I checked the route in the FOSUserBundle config (bearing in mind, I have not altered this file or anything within the friendsofsymfony directory):

```
<route id="fos_user_resetting_reset" path="/reset/{token}" methods="GET POST">
   <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Resetting:reset</default>
</route>
```

And the URL being visited:

```
https://crm.mysite.co.uk/resetting/reset/sAt7xPNzW4AempvzK6m2xRRN7jI058xAQjbct7GgyqI
```

which as you can see clearly passes a token. I've had strange issues like this before, if for example I don't pass a default value in my route (even if there's clearly a token or some other required parameter passed) but since this is a separate bundle and is in XML rather than YML I don't know how to fix this. I'm not entirely sure why it's even throwing an error?

Any help with this appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to view inside your console the route inside your app by doing:

```
bin/console debug:route
```

In this list you can get all available url

A possibility is that you need to call only:

```
https://crm.mysite.co.uk/reset/sAt7xPNzW4AempvzK6m2xRRN7jI058xAQjbct7GgyqI
```

Comment: I tried `debug:route` and received the following info for the route in question: `fos_user_resetting_reset              GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /resetting/reset/{token}` so it looks like it is correct, but just not working correctly?

Comment: I did clear the cache fully before running the route debug, so can't be that. Do you know how to set a default value for the parameter in the XML format of routing?